# Opencart 3.0.3.7 Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I'm running ***Opencart 3.0.3.7*** on ***PHP 7.4*** and I'm getting this message in the error log:

`PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/site/public_html/catalog/model/extension/module/so_filter_shop_by.php on line 313`

`PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/site/public_html/catalog/model/extension/module/so_filter_shop_by.php on line 314`

The code is :

```
    foreach($query->rows as $result)
    {
        $data = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($result['product_id']);
        $price = $this->tax->calculate($data['price'], $data['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
        if ((float)$data['special']) {
            $price = $this->tax->calculate($data['special'], $data['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
        }

        $price = $this->currency->format($price, $this->session->data['currency']);
        if ($this->language->get('decimal_point') == ',') {
            $price = trim(str_replace(',', '.', $price));
        }
        else {
            $price = trim(str_replace(',', '', $price));
        }
        $price = trim(str_replace($currencies, '', $price));
        
        $data['price_soFilter'] = $price;

        $product_data[] = $data;
    }
    return $product_data;
}
```

Could anyone suggest a solution to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the `$price NOT NULL` try something like this:

```
if(is_null($price))
  {
   $price = '';
  } else {
   $price = $this->tax->calculate($data['price'], $data['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if(!empty($price)) {
   $price = $this->tax->calculate((float)$data['price'], $data['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
} else {
   $price = '';
}
```

Comment: Both codes didn't work as they showed red X in the editor. i will edit the complete code in the original question.